# Pytest hooks flow

Tags: pytest

I'm new to **pytest** and I can't find solution for my question.

I know about some pytest's hooks like ***pytest_addoption()*** and ***pytest_configure()***

I'm trying to figure if and how ***pytest_addoption()*** runs first and only then ***pytest_configure()***.

If anyone know where I can find some information or can share his knowledge.
Thanks!

Comment: I'd say this is not possible; `pytest` calls `pytest_addoption` hooks before `pytest_configure` and there's not much you can do about it. Monkeypatching the `Config` class isn't an option because it will break `pytest` internals. Why do you want to do that anyway? Describe your problem with a [mcve], maybe there's a way to solve it without hooks reordering.

Comment: @hoefling I didn't ask how to change this behaviour. I'm looking for explanation of the pytest flow, to understand how it implements the precedence of these functions. I want to make sure it really happens that **pytes_addoption** hooks before **pytest_configure** Can I rely on something here? couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The flow of the hooks in pytest are specified here:

https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/2.8.7/_modules/_pytest/hookspec.html

see first line in the docstring below

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    """ called after command line options have been parsed
    and all plugins and initial conftest files been loaded.
    This hook is called for every plugin.
    """
```